# Erro api Pagseguro 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, api, token

Ao criar a requisição /create-order na api, recebo o erro:

```
    "message": "[403 Forbidden] during [POST] to [https://sandbox.api.pagseguro.com/create-order/pay] [PagBankClient#payOrder(String,PaymentRequestDto)]: [{\"message\":\"Forbidden\"}\n]",
    "path": "/create-order"
```

Estou usando o feignClient com a configuração:

```
@FeignClient(name = "pagseguro-api", url = "https://sandbox.api.pagseguro.com", configuration = FeignConfig.class)
public interface PagBankClient {

    @PostMapping("/orders")
    OrderResponseDto createOrder(@RequestBody OrderRequestDto dto);
    @PostMapping("/{order_id}/pay")
    PaymentResponseDto payOrder(@PathVariable("order_id") String orderId, @RequestBody PaymentRequestDto dto);
    @PostMapping("/charges/{charge_id}/cancel")
    PaymentResponse cancelPayment(@PathVariable("charge_id") String chargeId,
                                  @RequestBody CancelPaymentRequest cancelRequest);
    @PostMapping("/certificates")
    CertificateResponse createCertificate();
}
```

o token está correto, passando o Bearer, conforme o código acima e por isso estou na dúvida.
Veja o meu service:

```
@Service
public class PaymentService {
    @Autowired
    private PagBankClient client;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Transactional
    public PaymentResponseDto pay(String orderId, PaymentRequestDto dto) {
        PaymentResponse paymentResponse = client.pagarPedido(orderId, dto);
        return modelMapper.map(paymentResponse, PaymentResponseDto.class);
    }
}

@Service
public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private PagBankClient client;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Transactional
    public OrderResponseDto createOrder(OrderRequestDto dto) {
        OrderResponse orderResponse = client.createOrder(dto);
        return modelMapper.map(orderResponse, OrderResponseDto.class);

    }
}
@Configuration
public class FeignConfig {
    @Value("${pagseguro-token-sandbox}")
    private String token;
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor pagSeguroAuthInterceptor() {
        return new ApiRequestInterceptor(token);
    }
}
public class ApiRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private final String token;


    public ApiRequestInterceptor(String token) {
        this.token = token;

    }

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        template.header("accept", "application/json");
        template.header("Authorization", token);
        template.header("content-type", "application/json");
    }
}
```

Estou passando a requisição /create-order e com erro no create-order/pay. Não estou entendendo este motivo do erro e não é explícito na documentação.

Criei um controller e service para o caminho /orders:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(name = "/create-order")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService service;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<OrderResponseDto> createOrder(@RequestBody OrderRequestDto dto) throws IOException {
        OrderResponseDto response = service.createOrder(dto);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(response);
    }
}
@Service
public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private PagBankClient client;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Transactional
    public OrderResponseDto createOrder(OrderRequestDto dto) {
        OrderResponseDto orderResponse = client.createOrder(dto);
        return modelMapper.map(orderResponse, OrderResponseDto.class);
    }
}
@RestController
@RequestMapping(name = "/create-pay")
public class PaymentController {

    @Autowired
    private PaymentService service;

    @PostMapping("/{order_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PaymentRequestDto> pagarPedido(@PathVariable("order_id") String orderId,
                                                         @RequestBody PaymentRequestDto dto) {
        PaymentResponseDto responseDto  = service.pay(orderId, dto);
        URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(responseDto .getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(dto);
    }
}
@Service
public class PaymentService {
    @Autowired
    private PagBankClient client;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Transactional
    public PaymentResponseDto pay(String orderId, PaymentRequestDto dto) {
        PaymentResponseDto paymentResponse = client.payOrder(orderId, dto);
        return modelMapper.map(paymentResponse, PaymentResponseDto.class);
    }
}
```

Agradeço se responderem.

Comment: Você [já fez essa pergunta](/q/587621/70) e já recebeu orientação lá. Para evitar duplicidade de informações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui.